# Conditional serialization for the whole model

Tags: c#, xml, json, serialization

When serializing a model in C#, it is possible to leverage the [`ShouldSerialize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53b8022e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) capability to define when a property should be serialized and when not.

Is there an out-of-the-box way to specify the same, but for the entire model (something like `ShouldSerializeSelf`, or an attribute `[SerializeWhen(Property=true)]`), in such a way that the class is only serialized when a given condition is met.

If there is nothing like that, I can always implement my own serialization routine, but if there is something already implemented, wouldn't want to do double work.

Comment: You are looking for [XmlIgnore] however you want it conditional.  You could write your own custom attribute for serializewhen as I don't think anything exists like you want "out of the box".

Comment: `XmlIgnore` doesn't work here - it's not about properties, I am talking about ignoring the whole model from the serialization stack (e.g. trying to serialize a list of `MyClass` instances).

Comment: you said "when a property should be serialized" so I thought it was about properties. My guess is that the question is too vague and people don't understand what you are trying to accomplish well enough to help you.  If you show some sample code you will likely get better help.